# Prevent naïve longest token matching in Marpa::R2::Scanless

Tags: perl, parsing, marpa

In the current implementation of the [Scanless Interface](https://metacpan.org/module/Marpa%3a%3aR2%3a%3aScanless) (SLIF) in the Marpa parser, the lexer seems to do longest token matching (LTM) in the following fashion:

1. All terminal symbols are tried to match at the current position in the input.
2. All but the longest matches are discarded.
3. These longest tokens are fed to the parser, which may or may not accept them.
4. If no tokens are accepted, the parse fails.

This produces frustrating parse fails when my grammar contains tokens that would match the longest substring, but cannot occur at the current position. Consider the following code:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings; use feature qw/say/; use utf8;

use Marpa::R2;
use Data::Dump;

my @data = ('! key : value', '! key:value');

my $grammar = Marpa::R2::Scanless::G->new({
    source => \<<'END_GRAMMAR',
        :default ::= action => [values]
        :start   ::= record

        :discard  ~  ws
        ws        ~  [\s]+

        record ::= ('!') key (':') value
        key     ~  [\w]+
        value   ~  [^\s]+
END_GRAMMAR
});


for my $data (@data) {
    my $recce = Marpa::R2::Scanless::R->new({
        grammar => $grammar,
        trace_terminals => 0, # set this to "1" to see how the tokens are recognized
    });

    $recce->read(\$data);

    my $val = $recce->value // die "no parse";

    say ">> $data";
    dd $$val;
}
```

This produces the output:

```
>> ! key : value
["key", "value"]
Error in SLIF G1 read: No lexemes accepted at position 2
* Error was at end of input
* String before error: ! key:value
Marpa::R2 exception at marpa.pl line 33.
```

Expected output:

```
>> ! key : value
["key", "value"]
>> ! key:value
["key", "value"]
```

After `!` was recognized, a `key` token must follow. During lexing at this position, the `value` token matches the longest substring `key:value` although it cannot occur at this position. Therefore, the parse fails.

**Question:** Is it possible to achieve the expected output *without* writing a manual lexer?

(I know that a lexer can query the recognizer for expected tokens, and could restrict itself to matching only these tokens, but I don't know how to convince the SLIF to do this for me.)

I am running Marpa::R2 v2.064 on perl5 v16.2

---

#### Edit

Following  Jeffrey Kegler's advice, I implemented a rule that will always match a longer substring than a plain `value` and is therefore preferred. Using a `pause` event, I can then parse it manually, although I have to keep a phantom rule around for correct semantics.

Here is the full, updated code incl. event handling and an updated test case:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings; use feature qw/say/; use utf8;

use Marpa::R2;
use Data::Dump;

my @data = ('! key : value', '! key:value', '! key :value', '! key: value');

my $grammar = Marpa::R2::Scanless::G->new({
    source => \<<'END_GRAMMAR',
        :default ::= action => [values]
        :start   ::= Record

        :discard  ~  ws
        ws        ~  [\s]+

        Record ::=
                ('!') Key (<Op colon>) Value # not directly used
            |   ('!') KeyValue
        Key     ~  key
        Value   ~  value
        KeyValue~  key <ws any> ':' <ws any> value
        :lexeme ~ KeyValue pause => before event => 'before KeyValue'
        <Op colon> ~ ':'

        key     ~  [\w]+
        value   ~  [^\s]+
        <ws any>~  [\s]*
END_GRAMMAR
});

my %events = (
    'before KeyValue' => sub {
        my ($recce, $string, $start, $length) = @_;
        my ($k, $o, $v) = split /(\s*:\s*)/, $string, 2;
        say STDERR qq(k="$k" o="$o" v="$v");
        my $pos = $start;
        $recce->lexeme_read('Key'      => $pos, length($k), $k);
        $pos += length $k;
        $recce->lexeme_read('Op colon' => $pos, length($o), $o);
        $pos += length $o;
        $recce->lexeme_read('Value'    => $pos, length($v), $v);
    },
);


for my $data (@data) {
    my $recce = Marpa::R2::Scanless::R->new({
        grammar => $grammar,
        trace_terminals => 0,
    });
    my $length = length $data;
    for (
        my $pos = $recce->read(\$data);
        $pos < $length;
        $pos = $recce->resume()
    ) {
        say STDERR "pause";
        my ($start, $length) = $recce->pause_span();
        my $str = substr $data, $start, $length;
        for my $event_data (@{ $recce->events }) {
            my ($name) = @$event_data;
            my $code = $events{$name} // die "no code for event $name";
            $recce->$code($str, $start, $length);
        }
    }

    my $val = $recce->value // die "no parse";

    say ">> $data";
    dd $$val;
}
```

This produces

```
>> ! key : value
["key", "value"]
>> ! key:value
["key", "value"]
>> ! key :value
["key", "value"]
>> ! key: value
["key", "value"]
```

which is the expected behaviour.

Comment: Crosspost to the [marpa-parser list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/marpa-parser/gJrzdoinWhA/s8QbFyfRcA8J)

Comment: Untested, but perhaps this might work -- the trouble arises when it thinks a string containing a colon is a value.  Write the grammar to treat these specially, but do a "pause before" on colon-containing values.  During the "pause" double-check and alter the input as required.  This is pretty "manual", but the overhead would be incurred only in the problem cases.

Comment: @JeffreyKegler I did try this (I can update the code if needed), but couldn't get the pause event to trigger, as a (colon-containing) value wouldn't be accepted in that position. This is consistent with the [docs](https://metacpan.org/module/Marpa::R2::Scanless::DSL#pause): *“A lexeme pause event does not occur, and has no effect, if […] The G1 grammar would reject that lexeme at that location.”* Which is the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: Oops!  Sorry.  You're right.

Comment: Another thought.  A rule of the form "record ::= ('!') <complex record>", where <complex record> contains no space and two or more colons.  "Pause before" <complex record>, separate the key and colon and value and lex them.  Then resume after the record.

Comment: @JeffreyKegler Thank you! That actually seems to work, although it feels awfully backwards. I updated my post with the code I used; I hope it isn't too wrong. I'll try to sufficiently familiarize myself with the SLIF internals to formulate a proposal for better longest token matching.

Comment: Glad I could help and sorry about the initial miscue.

Comment: @amon - this post looks unanswered - which can be a bad look for Perl and Marpa - but clearly it is answered.  Why not copy the answer to to the answer place and mark this as answered?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please note that since version [2.079_015](https://metacpan.org/release/JKEGL/Marpa-R2-2.079_015), Marpa supports the notion of [Longest Acceptable Tokens Matching](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/marpa-parser/p7XWq6eBc5A/wxvHsL3TQj4J), meaning that just adding:

```
lexeme default = forgiving => 1
```

to your grammar will produce the expected output. I.e.:

```
#!env perl -w
use strict;
use Marpa::R2;
use Data::Dump;
use feature qw/say/;

my $grammar = Marpa::R2::Scanless::G->new({source => \do {local $/; <DATA>}});
my @data = ('! key : value', '! key:value', '! key :value', '! key: value');

foreach (@data) {
    my $r = Marpa::R2::Scanless::R->new({grammar => $grammar});
    $r->read(\$_);
    my $val = $r->value;
    say ">> $_"; dd $$val;
}
__DATA__
:default ::= action => [values]
lexeme default = forgiving => 1
:start   ::= record

:discard  ~  ws
 ws        ~  [\s]+

record ::= ('!') key (':') value
key     ~  [\w]+
value   ~  [^\s]+
```

will give:

```
>> ! key : value
["key", "value"]
>> ! key:value
["key", "value"]
>> ! key :value
["key", "value"]
>> ! key: value
["key", "value"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Copied from the comments, per Ross's suggestion:

You could create a rule of the form `record ::= ('!') <complex record>`, where `<complex record>` contains no space and two or more colons.

1. [“Pause before”](https://metacpan.org/pod/Marpa::R2::Scanless::DSL#pause) `<complex record>` (checking for pauses with the [`pause_lexeme`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Marpa::R2::Scanless::R#pause_lexeme) or [`events` method](https://metacpan.org/pod/Marpa::R2::Scanless::R#events)).
2. Separate the key and colon and value and [lex them manually](https://metacpan.org/pod/Marpa::R2::Scanless::R#lexeme_read).
3. Then [`resume`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Marpa::R2::Scanless::R#resume) normal parsing after the record.

Comment: As of version 2.079_015, and the availability of Longest Acceptable Tokens matching, it is better to use that.  See Jean-Damien's post, below.